# Get Google+ ID from Google Contacts

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I'm pulling a user's contacts email addresses and names using the Google Contacts API. 
Is there a way to get those people's Google+ IDs as well?

Answer (score 6):

The contacts API will return a `profile` link if a G+ profile is linked with the contact entry.

Here's an example:

```
<gContact:website href='http://www.google.com/profiles/1234567890' rel='profile'/>
```

In that element's `href` attribute, `1234567890` is the person identifier that would match the `id` field of the relevant [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) from `people.list` of the Google+ People API.

Note that the `profile` link is not guaranteed to come back for a contact entry.  This occurs when the contact has not been linked to a Google+ profile.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I also figured out it only returns those profiles on the v3.0 of the API, which I had to specify in my calls (results from 1.0 are returned by default). https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#specifying_a_version