# Google Contacts API doesn't return website extended properties

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts-api

I've successfully got contacts information using the .NET library.

According to this question:

[Get Google+ ID from Google Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802267/get-google-id-from-google-contacts)

The contacts should be returned with an extended property called website that is a link to the contact google profile. However, none of my contacts are returned with this informations, and many of them are connected to a google profile.

I made sure I'm using the 3.0 version of the API but still no good...Does anyone knows what may be the problem?

Thanks!