# Reverse lookup of a phone number on Google+ (number -> name mapping)

Tags: google-plus

Android Kitkat has a new [smart callerid feature](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-57611098-94/google-to-display-google-photos-of-your-callers/) which I believe looks up the incoming phone call  against your google+ contacts and also against google+ business pages / google business listings. It's pretty smart and would be a good way to lookup phone numbers in general.

I've looked through the google+ API documentation and had a hunt for any other APIs, but I can't immediately see a way to do this via the google+ API (or even on the google+ website or main google website) - does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) might be your best bet, you can map contacts to Google+ IDs by [looking at the profile URLs for a given contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802267/get-google-id-from-google-contacts). While people can add phone numbers to their Google+ profiles, the Google+ API in the [Person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) does not expose that information even if it is public.